# How to disable this annoying notifications in K7 Total security?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I am using **K7 Total Security 15.1.0345** in Windows 7 OS. But I am getting this annoying notification every second:

[image]

How to disable this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that K7 Total Security is giving the right message :
Your computer is infected by a virus.
The file `spoolsv.exe` is a legitimate Windows file, but it resides in
`C:\Windows\System32`, not in `C:\Windows\SpeechsTracing`.

It is hard for me to say which is the virus.
It might be some evolution of
[WORM64_WMINE.A](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/threat-encyclopedia/malware/worm64_wmine.a),
or it might be another virus entirely.

I would suggest to at least to deep-scan your computer using several well-known
anti-virus products and see if they find anything and can fix the problem.

For more information about what you can do, see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

Answer (score 1):

Its Very Simple to Disable Notification

- Go to Search in windows
- Notifications and Action Settings
- Scroll down you will Find your Listing(For Ex. k7)
- If you do not want any notification turn off the button
- Or choose which one u dont need to

Answer (score -1):

**Go to settings**; type in the search "notifications and action"
Click on it; scroll down u will see "get notification from these senders" and select sort by "name" and now off the notifications from the k7 total control.

Comment: That's not a native Windows notification but a custom window. Also, there's clearly a virus infection and these dialogs are only a symptom - the proper fix is to remove the virus, not hide notifications.